# How to fixed 419 unknown status in XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes, xmlhttprequest, laravel-controller

I have an error in my `XMLHttpRequest()` when sending a post request to my url. When I check my console.log it says

```
this line of code:
xhr.send();

Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status)
```

Here's my script code using only pure javascript:

```
<!-- Get Parameters for gclid or token when user visits the website -->
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        try {
            var url_string = (window.location.href).toLowerCase();
            var url = new URL(url_string);
            // Get Gclid
            var token = url.searchParams.get("gclid");
    
            // gclid expires in 6 hours
            document.cookie = `gclid=${gclid}; max-age=21600`;
    
            // Sending a get request to laravel controller
            var base_url = window.location.origin; // get the base url
            var params = "gclid=" + gclid;
    
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", base_url+"/storetrackvisit?"+params, true);
            xhr.send();
    
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Issues with Parsing URL Parameter's - " + err);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I'm trying to pass parameters in this `XMLHttpRequest()` so that when users has this parameters.

Example:
`https://www.test.com/?gclid=312`

It will send a post request to my `storetrackvisit` page along with the parameters and save it to db:
`https://www.test.com/storetrackvisit?gclid=312`

```
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", base_url+"/storetrackvisit?"+params, true);
            xhr.send();
```

so that it will save to my controller like this:

**TrafficController**

```
public function storeParams(Request $request)
{
    $traffic = new TrafficTracking();

    if ($request->has('gclid')) { // check if key = gclid
        $traffic->traffic_type = 'gclid'; // store the key in db
        $traffic->traffic_value = $request->gclid;
    }

    if ($traffic->value === null) {
        return response()->noContent();
    }

    $traffic->ip_address = $request->ip();
    $traffic->domain = $request->getHttpHost();
    $traffic->save();
}
```

**web.php**

```
// Traffic Controller
Route::post('/storetrackvisit', 'TrafficController@storeParams')->name('user.store.trackvisit');
```

What seems to be an error in my `xhr.send();` returning a status of 419 (unknown status)?
Is it because there is no csrf token passed along with my `XMLHttpRequest` in javascript? If so, how do I pass it in the `XMLHttpRequest` or maybe what's causing the 419 (unkown status)?

Comment: you need to send csrf token `_token:<token>`  as it is protected by web middle ware

Comment: @KamleshPaul how do I tweak my code?

Comment: Add Csrf Tokens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually a `419 Error` means a missing [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-introduction) token from a request. You can handle it easily in two ways.

1. Change the route to `GET` if you're not sending any sensitive info.
2. Include a *CSRF* token in your request.

I will explain about point number 2, how can you include a *CSRF* token in your request.

Now, there are also two ways to include a *CSRF* token:

1. Call it in header.
2. Create a *HTML* input field containing token.

**1. Call it in Headers**

You can define *CSRF* token in your header like this,

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and then access it in JavaScript and set headers for it like this,

```
xhr.setRequestHeader(header, value);
```

**2.  Create a *HTML* input field containing token**

You can create an input field containg token like this,

```
<!-- It's a laravel blade directive, which creates an input field containing token -->
@csrf

<!-- or manually do it -->
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Get it in your JavaScript and send it as a parameter like this,

```
let csrfToken = document.getElementsByName("_token");
    
params += "&_token=" + csrfToken;
```